# Namespace Route MissingTemplate Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've checked 9 similar questions on this topic an none of them have helped. All the files are there.

You can see in the [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mnyyw.png), I have a views template in `views/admin/access/index.hmtl.erb` and yet I'm getting an error saying it doesn't exist. `admin/settings/index` is also not found. What could be going on?

Apologies in advance if this is a very simple mistake. I'd be so grateful for any help on this.

Exceptions:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate:

   Missing template admin/settings/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder]}


ActionView::MissingTemplate:

   Missing template admin/access/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder]}
```

Setting controller:

```
class Admin::SettingsController < ApplicationController

  def index

  end
```

Access Controller:

```
class Admin::AccessController < ApplicationController

  def index

  end
```

Routes (though shouldn't matter):

```
  namespace :admin do 
    resources :access, only: [:index, :update]
    resources :settings, only: [:index, :update]
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template name should be (extension `html.erb`):

```
views/admin/access/index.html.erb
```

but NOT:

```
views/admin/access/index.hmtl.erb
```

Comment: Exactly. Thank you! -though now I feel foolish